# Java & MySQL can have debug log?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using mysql to create a connection with my database. The code is working fine, but what if i enter a wrong username/pass/host/database can i get a log message with the part is wrong? Here is the code:

```
private void connectDatabase()
{
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/"
                + database + "?autoReconnect=true", username, password);
        System.out.println("[MySQL] The connection to MySQL is made!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("[MySQL] The connection to MySQL couldn't be made! reason: "
                        + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Ex: I enter a wrong password and i get this error log:

```
[MySQL] The connection to MySQL couldn't be made! reason: Wrong password.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can try and check

Comment: I want to try, but the idea is i don't know where to start.

Comment: Your code is fine, except the message you will get  would be more detailed.

Comment: Yea, the message i want to edit. I dunno how to get error case to build my custom message. Any idea what i need to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL, you will get an SQLExcpetion, something like below:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
...
```

SQLException will have SQLState = 28000,  and vendorCode = 1045

Comment: I was using default java mysql. Installing jdbc on server mysql host and using it with eclipse maybe will work. Default java mysql send only 1 message: "Could not create connection to database server"

Comment: There are variety of errors - the one I have shown above is specific for wrong password.  If server is down, then,  you will get different error